# MySQL issue in DataSet

Tags: mysql, dataset

I am using the latest version of MySQL connector to .NET and Visual Studio 2008. I dragged and dropped all tables from the MYSQL database to VS 2008 dataset GUI successfully. When I was going to add a new stored procedure to the dataset, Visual Studio environment just refused doing so.

Is there any solutions around this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also have the same issue. I've been looking for a solution to this problem for almost a year now. 
Doing a search on google shows that the issue has been raised in the MySQL Bugs tracker/forum.

I thought that the issue would be fixed in version 6.04 of the connector, just downloaded and tested it, but still unable to drag and drop stored procedures from the server explorer.

I'm thinking of using the workaround of hardcoding the strongly typed datasets.

Maybe you should try that in the meantime.